# Why isn't this broadcast stream working when I add a second listener

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I can't understand why this broadcast stream doesn't work.

I'm sending the data from _auth.onAuthStateChanged to a new StreamController so that I can have more control over the stream.

The code below works fine, but as soon as I uncomment the line `_userStream.listen(_handleUserStream);`, the stream stops working, even though the userStream is a broadcast stream.

I've tried initialising the StreamController as a StreamController.broadcast(), but then it doesn't even work at all even with just one listener.

```
class AuthService() {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  StreamController<FirebaseUser> _userStreamController;
  Stream<User> _userStream;
  Stream<User> get userStream => _userStream;


  AuthService() {
    initStream();
  }

  initStream() async {
    _userStreamController = StreamController<FirebaseUser>();
    _userStream = _userStreamController.stream
        .asBroadcastStream()
        .asyncMap(_userFromFirebaseUser);

    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((event) {
      _userStreamController.add(event);
    });

    // _userStream.listen(_handleUserStream);
  }

  ... other methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the streamController in the first line of the initStream as a broadcast stream directly and then you can use the stream directly as seen below

```
class AuthService() {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  StreamController<FirebaseUser> _userStreamController;
  Stream<User> _userStream;
  Stream<User> get userStream => _userStream;


  AuthService() {
    initStream();
  }

  initStream() async {
    _userStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();
    _userStream = _userStreamController.stream;

    _userStream.listen(_handleUserStream);

    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((event) {
      _userStreamController.add(event);
    });
  }

  ... other methods
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I tried initialising as a `StreamController.broadcast()` but no luck. Did you try this and it worked?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint or print statement inside onAuthStateChanged listener to confirm that events are actually coming in